# Nginx переадресация https://site.com на https://www.site.com

Tags: apache, nginx, redirect

занимаюсь переадресацией и не получается сделать простую переадресацию с https://site.com на https://www.site.com. Чтобы при вводе https://site.com перенаправлялось на https://www.site.com

Вот конфиг моего nginx сервера.

```html
     server {

        root /var/www/site/public;
        index ../views/index.html;
        server_name www.site.com;


        location /img/ {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3010;
          proxy_cache off;
          proxy_cache_key "$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args";
      }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3010;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


     
     location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|css|js|html)$ {
                 root /var/www/site/public;
                 expires 1y;
                 access_log off;
                 add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

    
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/fullchain.pem;          ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/privkey.pem;       include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}



server {

        if ($host = site.com) {
                return 301 https://www.site.com;
        }


       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
       server_name site www.site.com;
       return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Есть у кого-то варианты как мне сделать это правильно?

Answer (score 1):

вам надо добавить ещё один блок `server`, в котором указать:

- `server_name` с переадресуемым именем
- тот же набор директив `listen` и `ssl_*`, что и в уже существующем блоке, обслуживающем имя `www.site.com`
- директиву перенаправления (например, `return`)

примерно так:

```
server {
  server_name site.com;
  listen ...;
  ...
  ssl_...;
  ...
  return 301 https://www.site.com;
}
```

p.s. ну и не забудьте проконтролировать, что в используемом сертификате упомянуты и `site.com` и `www.site.com`, а так же не забудьте про указание ключа, которым подписан сертификат (в приведённом вами конфиге он почему-то не наблюдается).

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите конфиг редиректа в отдельный блок server

```
# перенаправление 
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen 443;
  server_name site.com;
  server_tokens off;
  return 301 https://www.site.com$request_uri;
}

# основной конфиг
server {
    server_name www.site.com
    # остальной конфиг главного сервера
}
```